# ffmpeg get md5 from local m3u8

Tags: ffmpeg, md5, decode, m3u8

I am trying to get an m3u8 md5 output with ffmpeg

`ffmpeg  -y -map 0 -an -sn -f md5 - -i index.m3u8`

but getting an error

`[https @ 0x556ad6947520] Protocol not on whitelist 'file,crypto'!
index.m3u8: Invalid argument`

I tried adding the argument (documented [here](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#Protocol-Options))

`-protocol_whitelist file,http,https,tcp,tls`

But I am still getting the same result, if I am using a network m3u8 (http) everything works as expected.

```
$  /usr/bin/ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,http,https,tcp,tls  -y -map  0:0 -an -sn -f md5 - -i index.m3u8 
ffmpeg version 3.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 5.3.0 (Alpine 5.3.0)
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/lib --bindir=/usr/local/bin --disable-doc -- disable-static --enable-shared --disable-ffplay --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-version3 --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-gpl --enable-avresample --enable-postproc --enable-nonfree --disable-debug --enable-small --enable-openssl
 libavutil      55. 34.100 / 55. 34.100
 libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
 libavformat    57. 56.100 / 57. 56.100
 libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
 libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
 libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
 libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
 libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
 libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
[https @ 0x5589b5d435a0] Protocol not on whitelist 'file,crypto'!
index.m3u8: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Is your ffmpeg compiled with either openssl or gnutls?

Comment: @Mulvya --enable-openssl , why? does that affect md5 somehow?

Comment: It's needed for https input. Show your entire command and console output.

Comment: @Mulvya edited with full input and output

Comment: Try `ffmpeg  -y -protocol_whitelist file,http,https,tcp,tls -i index.m3u8 -map 0 -an -sn -f md5 -`

Comment: @Mulvya works! thanks a lot. what was I missing here?

Comment: Option placement matters. Options before `-i` apply to that input. Options after an input but before an output name or pipe apply to that output.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments are ok, they just need to be in the correct order:

```
ffmpeg -y -protocol_whitelist file,http,https,tcp,tls -i index.m3u8 -map 0 -an -sn -f md5 -
```

as documented in the manual and help :

```
ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...
```

Options before -i apply to that input. Options after an input but before an output name or pipe apply to that output